# vuetify v-slider Cannot get new position after click on slider

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-slider

In my AudioPlayer component, I have a v-slider 
I cannot get the value after cha,ging the slide position ;-)

```
      <v-slider @change="setPosition()" :value="trackProgress" :v-model="percentage" thumb-label></v-slider>


    data() {
      return {
        percentage: 0
      };
    },
    computed: {
        trackProgress: function() {
          return this.progress * 100;
        }
      },
    methods: {
        setPosition() {
          console.log("SET POSITION: ", this.percentage); // always 0 !!!
          // this.setProgress(this.percentage / 100);
          // this.togglePlayback();
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `:` on the `v-model`-attribute, which lets Vue think it's a binded prop with the name "v-model", rather than the `v-model` itself.

Replace `:v-model` with `v-model`:

```
<v-slider @change="setPosition()" :value="trackProgress" :v-model="percentage" thumb-label></v-slider>
```

should be

```
<v-slider @change="setPosition()" :value="trackProgress" v-model="percentage" thumb-label></v-slider>
```